# 新規図面を作成する際に、指定したテンプレートが適用されない

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2023用にvb.netを使用して、新規図面を作成する処理を開発しています。
新規図面用に複数の画層を定義したテンプレートファイルを用意しています。
GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentCollectionExtension.Addの引数に、そのテンプレートファイルを指定しているのですが、作成された図面にはテンプレートファイルに定義した画層が見つかりません。
新規図面の作成方法が間違っているのでしょうか。
対象方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

> 新規図面の作成方法が間違っているのでしょうか。

間違っていないと思います。
ご提示の方法と同じAPIを使い、新規図面を作成する処理を試してみましたが、
指定したテンプレートファイルをもとに正常に新規図面が作成されます。

引数のテンプレートファイルのパスは正常に指定できているか等、
ソースコードを再確認されてみたらいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
フォルダの区切りが￥ではなく、/になっていたのが原因でした。